# Sim is not getting deactivated in cm12.1

Tags: cyanogenmod, dual-sim, micromax

I am using CM12.1 on my Canvas Nitro. Everything seems fine, except single sim deactivation. Even if I try to deactivate any sim, it does not get deactivated.

Comment: Which build of CM12.1 is it? Is it nightly or stable?

Comment: Its the unofficial build by fire855 which is ported to Canvas Nitro A310.